# Elasticsearch index field with wildcard and search for it

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a document with a field "serial number". That serial number is ABC.XXX.DEF where XXX indicates wildcards. XXX can be \d{3}[a-zA-Z0-9].

So users can search for:

> ABC.123.DEF
>
> ABC.234.DEF
>
> ABC.XYZ.DEF

while the document only includes

> ABC.XXX.DEF

When a user queries ABC.123.DEF i need a hit on that document containing ABC.XXX.DEF. As other documents might contain ABC.DEF.XXX and must not be hit I am running out of ideas with my basic elasticsearch knowledge.

Do I have to attack the problem from the query side or when analyzing/tokenizing the pattern?

Can anyone give me an example how to approach that problem?

Comment: By "where XXX indicates wildcards" what do you mean? How it is getting stored? Could you add an example ?

Comment: I am about to index an entity that represents a page. there is a field: "serial number pattern" and it holds ABC.XXX.DEF so users can enter data without knowing about regex and stuff.

Comment: May you show your current mapping?

Comment: its really not about a mapping. its more about how to tackle that problem without custom queries. I want to deal with this problem via indexing alone but do not really know about the approach. I do not know how to index ABC.XXX.DEF so the same document is found via the exact query string ABC.123.DEF.

Answer (score 0):

As long as serial number is well defined the first solution that comes to my mind is to split serial number into three parts ("part1", "part2" and "part3", for example) and index them as three separate fields. Parts consisting of wildcards should have special value or may not be indexed at all. Then at query time I would split serial number provided by user in the same way. Assuming that parts consisting of wildcards are not indexed my query would look like this:

```
"query": {
  "bool": {
    "must":[
      {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "match": {
                "part1": "ABC"
              }
            },
            {
              "bool": {
                "must_not": {
                  "exists": {
                    "field": "part1"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      ... // Similar code for other parts
    ] 
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks! actually i would love to tackle the problem completely via elasticsearch. I would need to implement logic for the query, like parsing the search expression and create a custom query for your approach. I am looking for a solution that elasticsearch can handle by just receiving the query string.